# Java DatagramSocket freezes on initialization

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I'm writing a piece of UDP networking program (client - server), and I've run into some trouble.

I want to use streams to I/O data, so I googled "udp inputstream" and found [UDPInputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/UDPInputStream.htm) and [UDPOutputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/UDPOutputStream.htm). When I try to use these, however, the program gets stuck when trying to initialize the UDPOutputStream.

This is the line in my code that freezes:

```
outStream = new UDPOutputStream(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), port);
System.out.println("UDP output stream initialized."); // <-- doesn't get called
```

I checked out the source of the UDPOutputStream, the code gets stuck on this line:

```
dsock = new DatagramSocket();
```

Why does the execution hang up on this line? On the server side, I still use my "old", non-stream version of a simple UDP code, and it works. The socket is initialized the same way and it doesn't hang up. I tried to put a port number to the initialization, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: A UDP socket bound to 127.0.0.1 can't send anywhere outside the localhost. Are you sure that's what you want? If not, try null instead of the InetAddress.

Comment: If you want to treat data as a stream, UDP is absolutely the wrong protocol. TCP is what you should use.

Comment: The server runs on the same computer (although on different port), so yeah, 127.0.0.1 is the address I want. It shouldn't be the problem, though, because it works on the serverside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host machines have more than one network interface (for example, 127.0.0.1 for the loopback interface and some other address for the network card; there may be more than one network card).

If you bind to the loopback address *127.0.0.1* then you'll only be able to receive packets sent locally. If want to receive packets sent over the network from a remote machine you must bind to the local IP address (e.g. 192.168.1.100).

Try following:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
outStream = new UDPOutputStream(addr, port);
```